# Unable to make changes to cloned repository as files that are changed aren't shown as being modified using git status command

Tags: git, github

I was following a tutorial on youtube and became stuck. After researching and trying to solve the problem for around 15 hours I gave up and have just been procrastinating asking on here. So the issue is that when I have made changes to a file that I have cloned from the online repository, it does not show as being a 'modified file' in VS code.

These are the steps I took:

1. Create an online repository with a README.md
2. Make a folder in vs code to be able to clone the repo into
3. Clone repository to local machine using the `git clone` command
4. `cd` into the repo (if the name of the repo is testing which has a readme file I would do `cd testing`)
5. Use `ls -force` which shows:

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d--h--        14/07/2023   2:35 PM                .git
-a----        14/07/2023   2:27 PM             40 README.md
```

6. Change the readme file within vs code
7. Use git status

This git status returns:

```
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

8. Use `git branch -a` which returns:

```
* main
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/main
```

9. Use `git branch -u origin main` which returns:

```
branch 'main' set up to track 'origin/main'.
```

10. Make new changes to the README file
11. Use `git status` which returns with a (you guessed it):

```
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I have also tried deleting and re-installing both vs-code and git on my laptop and just alot of other things that after 1 week of procrastinating I've forgotten what I had done. Pretty rough for a first time user of git but it may be a blessing in disguise if I can get it fixed. I learned alot about git that I wouldn't have known if this hadn't happened. Anyways, any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I have a suspicion that this may be a problem with the HEAD branch since, from what I know, the HEAD branch stores the changes you made. This is just a guess though and I didn't dig any deeper because I was already at my wit's end :)

Comment: Are you saving the file after making changes, and are you definitely in the right directory? Also the `force` flag isn't necessary in a situation like this (and also isn't portable outside of the BSD/Mac world)

Comment: Im not mad at all. So all this time its because i hadnt saved the file... i am very kalm right now.
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   README.md. I've been waiting to see that modified tag for a long time.

Comment: Thank you very much you have helped me alot. also what would you suggest I do instead of force? Ive tried to use ls -la but it doesnt work for me.